# adding the values/properties to the result object - List<MyDTO> before returning to the UI

Tags: java, spring

I am working on spring MVC application.

I have got the results from the service call as shown in the below code.
I want to add two string elements before I send back the results to the UI.
Below is the code in my spring controller class:

```
MyTestDTO myTestDTOObj = new MyTestDTO();
myTestDTOObj.setSid(22);
myTestDTOObj.setUserName("James");
myTestDTOObj.setWelcomeName("James Gold Customer XXX");

List<MyTestDTO> results  = myServiceCall.getMyResultsData(myTestDTOObj);
 //in the above results object i don't have the username and welcomeName which i want to return to the web page from spring controller.
```

MyTestDTO.java contains the below properties and its setters and getters:

```
public class MyTestDTO implements Serializable{
private int sid;
private String userName;
private String welcomeName;
...
//few ore properties
//setters and getters

}
```

Please advise how to add the username and welcomeName in the results object in the controller so that I can get that values on my web page.

Comment: well what is `getMyResultsData` doing?

Comment: It seems like you want to get some data in that kind of method name. not adding it. show us `getMyResultsData` code.

Comment: Show your service class

Answer (score 0):

You need another DTO:

```
public class AnotherDTO {

    private List<MyTestDTO> results;
    private String username;
    private String welcomeName;

    //getters and setters

}
```

Simply return this object.